# Rails test without saving to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, testing

I'm lost with how to temporarily in a test, have data saved to the database, but then not exist there after the tests are finished running.

Can anyone give me some hints as the best way to approach this?

Comment: Are you testing with Rspec or manually? If manually, you can use the console in sandbox mode.

Comment: Database is local, I run "rails s" and then can access and make changes in the browser or in code.
Does Rspec let you for instance, do modelObject = ModelObject.new, modelObject.save, saves to the db, then when you stop the server, the saved data is no longer in the db?

Comment: Actually RSpec would do everything for you. It is a testing tool. You should definitively check it out : http://rspec.info. Alternately, you could just write your seeds data and repopulate the database every time you run the server.

Comment: Rspec's default mode is to execute every test in a transaction that is rolled back after the test is complete, so the database is clean. You have to turn this feature off explicitly to prevent cleanup!

Comment: REALLY? Awesome, I kept seeing that word popup, but didnt' think it did that!!!

Comment: I found writing tests in Rspec hard when I started. That's why I suggested the seed solution if you need a quick fix - though in the long run, it's totally worth it.

Comment: Also if you're manually messing around with stuff in the console, just run `rails c -s` which will run the console in sandbox mode. Any changes you make will get rolled back when you exit the console session.

Comment: @Justin D.  No, this is perfect. I kept seeing Rspec pop up, it WILL be a late night, but I need to call saves and update_attributes to quite a few things. I don't know anything about seeding, but it sounds like putting hours into this will be easier in the end.